# Just curious Is there any functional difference between the two code samples?

Tags: javascript

I am curious whether there's any functional difference or any potential bug that may arise by using code sample 1. where it would return inside the for loop as opposed to `break`ing it manually and then returning the result as seen in 2.

1.

```
function is_hid(dev_path, hid_arr){
  for (let i = 0; i < hid_arr.length; i++) {
    if( dev_path == hid_arr[i].path){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

2. 

```
function is_hid(dev_path, hid_arr){
  var result = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < hid_arr.length; i++) {
    if( dev_path == hid_arr[i].path){
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: first one will return `undefined` if nothing is found, the second will return `false`.

Comment: Also, both can just be replaced with `hid_arr.some(x => x.path == dev_path)`